# graph explorer api get events from page return empty data array

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Have try to get public events data from a page, through facebook graph api explorer like
/{page-id}/events with a token that I produce from the graph. When I debug the access token I can see that I have the following permissions

```
public_profile, user_likes, user_activities, user_events, user_about_me
```

I have test it in some other pages and works fine like graph.facebook.com/cocacola/Events as a example, I get the Array of Events.

The problem come that in the page that I trying to retrieve the events I get an empty Data array and I don't know why. The thing is that if I try to get the events from groups it works but when I try to retrive the events of this page (others too)  it just not work. The graph request is

```
348101891945454/events
```

Also it does not work when I try to retrieve my events.. me/events/

Some help on this please. Is something with the configuration/settings of page?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there are no current events for that page. You need to apply the since and until parameters to get a response.

e.g. `348101891945454/events?since=1325462400`

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works now. Didn't think about it -.-"